# Data not showing in MatPlot Histogram Plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, histogram

I am trying to generate a list of values, and then plot those list of values using the MatPlotLib Hist function. This is what my graph looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7P8Q.png

I've followed this process for two other graphs with no trouble at all, for some reason this one is giving me trouble.

This is my code:

```
for y in range(Nloop):

    e0_y = e_List[y]  # Takes the a value from these list and sets it equal to this variable
    a0_y = a_List[y]   # Same thing ^^^
    Term_1 = (a0_y ** 4)/((m_tot**3)*eta)
    Term_2 = (1 - e0_y**2)**(7/2)
    Unit_Conversions = (c**5/G**3)
    tau = (3/85) * Term_1 * Term_2 * Unit_Conversions
    T_List[y] = tau


 MIN, MAX = 1, 1e12
 Nbins = 25
 bins = 10 ** np.linspace(np.log10(MIN), np.log10(MAX), Nbins)
 plt.hist(T_List, bins=25, histtype='step')
 plt.xscale('log')  # x-axis now has a log-scale
 plt.yscale('log')
 plt.title('Distribution')
 plt.xlabel('T [sec]')
 plt.ylabel('Frequency')
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Not sure if it is the problem, but maybe you want to pass `bins=bins` to `plt.hist` since you are calculating the bins before.

Comment: what happens if you omit `plt.yscale('log')`?

Comment: I tried to run your code and it told me `Nloop` was undefinted. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PaulH Sorry, I didn't want to include the whole code since it was rather long... Here's a link to the most updated file on GitHub:
https://github.com/ahabbs20/MergerTime

Also, even if I omit `plt.yscale('log')`, it does nothing.

Comment: @Valentino, I've edited the code to do that, but it doesn't seem to change much of anything...

Comment: Could you explain better what do you expect? Running your code (I didn't change anything, just grabbed the content from the github link you provided) i get [this histogram](https://imgur.com/5w7UxWl), which seems quite fine to me.